# Wrapping results in Table

Tags: php

I have a php code that is echoing results from a database.
Code here:

```
<?php

   $db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "garyline_master");

   if(isset($_GET['keywords'])) {

        $keywords = $db->escape_string($_GET['keywords']);

        $query = $db->query("
            SELECT productID, productName, description
            FROM promo
            WHERE productID LIKE '%{$keywords}%'
            OR productID LIKE '%{$keywords}%'
        ");
   ?>

   <div class="resul-count">
    Found <?php echo $query->num_rows; ?> Results.
    </div>

    <table border="1" align="center">   
    <?php

        if($query->num_rows){
            while($r = $query->fetch_object()){
            ?>
            <div class="result">
                    <tr><?php 
                    echo $r->productID;
                    echo $r->productName;
                    echo $r->description;
            ?>
            </tr>
                </div>
    </table>
            <?php
        }

}
}   
?>
```

I'm trying to figure out the proper way to write the code. to wrap the results in a table  Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: So what is the error?

Comment: Code should be in the question, not an external link. Please, take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, the part where're you're echoing the results here:

```
while($r = $query->fetch_object()){
        ?>
        <div class="result">
                <tr><?php
                echo $r->productID;
                echo $r->productName;
                echo $r->description;
        ?>
        </tr>
```

First of all, the div with class "result" strikes me as strange. Why not simply apply that class to the tr? Secondly, you have no "td" elements. Maybe this is what you need:

```
while($r = $query->fetch_object()){
    echo '<tr class="result">';
    echo "<td>$r->productID</td>";
    echo "<td>$r->productName</td>";
    echo "<td>$r->description</td>";
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Properly forming your table elements with the results of your query should give you what you are looking for.

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $r->productID;   ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r->productName; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r->description; ?></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some errors in the table structure in the html representation.

- do not use "div" inside the table (you can do inside a td, see next topic)
- your data has to be placed in a "td" tag, that tag can contain html

A clean table in html looks like this:

```css
table {
  font-family: sans;
}

th,
td {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Col1 Head</th>
    <th>Col2 Head</th>
    <th>Col3 Head</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1/1</td>
    <td>1/2</td>
    <td>1/3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2/1</td>
    <td>2/2</td>
    <td>2/3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3/1</td>
    <td>3/2</td>
    <td>3/3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So in your code it could look like this (untested):

```
<table>
<?php
if($query->num_rows){
  while($r = $query->fetch_object()){
    ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $r->productID; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r->productName; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r->description; ?></td>
      </tr>
<?php
  }
}   
?> 
</table>
```

One could say a lot about good practices in php application design that you do not use, but so far it can be called a quick solution.